# How to convert a group of videos to 320x240 with letterboxing in ffmpeg with varying dimensions?

Tags: ffmpeg, powershell, encoding, mpeg

I have a directory with around 660 videos in it. I have written a PowerShell script to loop over the files in the directory - but I am stuck at the conversion piece with ffmpeg.

The most recent command I tried was this:

```
$destination = 'Z:\sirenvideos\new-encoded'

Get-ChildItem -Path '.\'   -Filter '*.*' | ForEach-Object {
  $target = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath ([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, '.mkv'))
  ffmpeg -i "$($_.FullName)"    -vf "scale=iw/1.333333:ih:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=320:240:-1:-1:color=black,setsar=1" -r 30000/1001 -x265-params lossless=1 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart "$target"
}
```

This is not working.

Of these videos, some are 1920x1080, some are 1280x768, some are 720x480 - you get the idea. I need to convert all of these to 320x240 while preserving the original aspect ratio (using letterboxing). What is the best way to do this?

Here is the error output I am getting.

```
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0000012e1c3f8a80] Input area -320:-150:640:390 not within the padded area 0:0:320:240 or zero-sized
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0000012e1c3f8a80] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pad_1
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

Comment: What part of the script isn't working? Is FFMPEG working on the files at all, or is the script failing before then?

Comment: It just doesnt add the letterboxing, it creates a total padded video

Comment: @music2myear - i added the error that i receive on a large number of the videos that fail